# Why does Spring Security not provide character array parameters for passwords

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

If the best practice for handling sensitive data in Java is to use character arrays, why do most methods in Spring Security use String or CharSequence? For example the methods on Encryptors take CharSequence. In fact, looking at the source code of those methods, they actually end up converting the CharSequence to a String. Since the folks on that project have more lifetimes of experience in these matters than I will ever have, I feel like I must be missing something. Does anyone have any insight into how to pass sensitive data to these methods?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> You really cannot do much to reduce the life of the password in a
> Servlet container because the HttpServletRequest returns the HTTP
> parameters as a String. So Spring Security could take all the measures
> in the world to reduce the lifetime of the password but it wouldn't
> make a difference because the String would already exist.
>
> -Rob Winch (Spring Security)

[Source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3238)

Comment: Thanks Rob for the quick reply. I was afraid of that. In other words, I was afraid that the design assumptions of the past would dictate the designs we all must now live with regardless of their security implications. I will embrace the world in which I live.